# How can I install a package on OpenBSD?

Tags: ftp, openbsd

I installed OpenBSD and then proceeded to download firefox using the PKG_PATH environment. 
It worked and seemed to run reasonably well but then, wanting to try another browser, I deleted firefox using `pkg_delete` (which of course wasn't necessary).

I now find myself unable to download any browser as for some reason the system now doesn't recognize any ftp server I try to connect to. Every time I try to using 'export PKG_PATH', I get the message 'no such directory'.

Any hints at what happened and what I might do ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the environment variable PKG_PATH, you don't need it. If you installed the system using a mirror, the package tools are smart enough to use the same mirror to download the packages.

Otherwise, run this command as root:

```
echo 'https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD' > /etc/installurl
```

If you're using -stable, `pkg_add` will download the packages from there.

If you're running -current and `pkg_add` can't find the packages, use `pkg_add -Dsnap` instead. For example: `pkg_add -Dsnap -Vi chromium firefox`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, when running the command as root and then using pkg_add to download the packages, I get the following message:   ftp: SSL write error: ocsp verify failed: ocsp response not current. I am not sure what this means, is there another solution I might try ?

Comment: Try these commands as root: `rcctl set ntpd flags -s`, `rcctl start ntpd` and `rcctl enable ntpd`. Wait a few seconds and then run the pkg_add command.

Answer (score 0):

You bumped into something that happens before every OpenBSD release.  OpenBSD is [developed on a "single track"](http://www.openbsd.org/papers/asiabsdcon2009-release_engineering/): the source tree is tagged as 6.4, a release is made, developments continue for about 6 months and are made available as snapshots, until the devs find that things have changed and are stable enough to warrant a new release, at which point the tree is tagged as 6.5 and so on.

This means that for a short period of time (i.e. some days before a new release) the kernel is marked as "6.5" instead of "snapshot".  When you use `pkg_add`, so it'll look for packages for the kernel you are running, it'll look for "6.5" packages, which will only be available later hence the `no such directory`.  As answered by Rufo, adding `-D snap` to `pkg_add` will solve the (temporary) problem, by telling `pkg_add` to look for "snapshot" packages, even with a "release" kernel.  From `man pkg_add`:

```
snap
  Force ‘%c’ and ‘%m’ to expand to ‘snapshots’, even on a release kernel
```

This is obviously not ideal, but it has been time-tested and is what works better for the OpenBSD devs (see the presentation linked above to know more about OpenBSD's release engineering).  Adding `-D snap` for a few days before releases once every two months is a small price to pay for using snapshots.